# why CoUninitialize block thread

Tags: multithreading, com

MSDN says:CoUninitialize should be called on application shutdown, as the last call made to the COM library after the application hides its main windows and falls through its main message loop. If there are open conversations remaining, CoUninitialize starts a modal message loop and dispatches any pending messages from the containers or server for this COM application. By dispatching the messages, **CoUninitialize ensures that the application does not quit before receiving all of its pending messages.** Non-COM messages are discarded.

But I don't know what kind message is COM message and what operation can cause COM Library must wait COM messages, how do I avoid this action?

please give me a link or a keyword, thank you!

Comment: An STA thread must pump a message loop, rock-hard requirement.  Exiting the message loop because the user closed the main window instantly violates that requirement, very high odds for deadlock when a worker thread was busy making a call that crosses an apartment boundary.  CoUninitialize() takes over the duty.

Comment: BTW you should make sure all objects have been `Release`d before calling CoUninitialize

Comment: No need to tell COM and non-COM messages. You call `CoUninitialize` if you have to. If it blocks, the bug you have already happened in past (esp. some COM interfaces were not released properly).

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake that CoUninitialize dosen't block thread, IUnknow::Release dose, and also don't know why...